# cellForRowAtIndexPath returns null but really need similar method

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates, interface-builder

I have a `UITableView` in my `UITableViewController` (lol, obviously) but I need to get a cell at a given index inside the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Now, my cells are static and I create them in the interface builder. If I call

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:previously_selected_cell.integerValue inSection:0]];
```

it returns null for the cell. I only have 3 static cells in 1 sections. I tried both sections 0 and 1 and both return null.

Currently I have removed the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method because if I add it, it will clear the `UITableView` of all my static cells.

Is there a method I can call in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` that will return a cell at a given index?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I checked out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683881/cellforrowatindexpath-returns-null-value) but I'm using static cells without cellForRowAtIndexPath so that question didn't help. :(

EDIT2: I'm trying to set the accessory type of the cell when the view loads. But only on a certain cell, that cell being the one the user selected before he quit the app.

```
#import "AutoSyncSettings.h"
#import "CDFetchController.h"


@implementation AutoSyncSettings

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CDFetchController *cdfc = [[CDFetchController alloc] init];
    NSFetchedResultsController *results = [cdfc getFetchedResultsControllerWithEntityName:@"SETTINGS"];
    NSArray *objects = [results fetchedObjects];
    NSNumber *sync_setting;

    if(objects.count > 0)
    {     
        NSManagedObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        sync_setting = [object valueForKey:@"wifi_setting"];

        NSLog(@"(Settings)sync_setting: %@",sync_setting);
    NSLog(@"(Settings)sync_setting int value: %i",sync_setting.integerValue);
    NSLog(@"(Settings)TableView: %@",self.tableView);

//cell is null, even after this.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:wifi_settings.integerValue inSection:0]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
//cell is still null. WHY OH WHY? :(

        objects = nil;
    }

    cdfc = nil;
    results = nil;
    objects = nil;
    sync_setting = nil;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]; i++)
    {
        if([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
            [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    CDFetchController *cdfc = [[CDFetchController alloc] init];
    NSFetchedResultsController *results = [cdfc getFetchedResultsControllerWithEntityName:@"SETTINGS"];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [results managedObjectContext];
    NSArray *objects = [results fetchedObjects];

    if(objects.count > 0)
    {

        NSManagedObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

        NSNumber *sync_setting = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
        [object setValue:sync_setting forKey:@"sync_interval"];
        [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"id"];

        [ErrorHandler saveMoc:context];
    }
    else
    {
        //INSERT NEW OBJECT
        NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SETTINGS" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSNumber *sync_setting = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
        [object setValue:sync_setting forKey:@"sync_interval"];
        [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"id"];

        [ErrorHandler saveMoc:context];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I believe `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should still work; are you sure that `previously_selected_cell.integerValue` has the value you expect?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, it's 2 currently. If comment-in the cellForRowAtIndexPath all my static cells vanish. I believe it tries to create new cells...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve - why are you trying to get the cell at that index in your viewWillAppear method?

Comment: @NickBull Sorry, will edit my question. I want to add a checkmark accessory to the previously selected cell, the `previously_selected_cell` variable gets stored even if the app quits/crashes

Comment: Why don't you set that in your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your tableview delegate when you are requested the index path that matches the previously set one?

Comment: @NickBull the cells are static, and I create them in the interface builder so thats not an option, but thank for suggesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a project doing exactly this and it works perfectly. However, it *doesn't* work unless you call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` before trying to access the cells in this manner.

The base implementation presumably loads in the cells from the storyboard.

Comment: viewWillAppear loads fine automatically, this is not my problem though. Thanks for posting anyway.

Comment: Yes, sorry `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. In that method is where I want to ge the cell. `- (void)viewDidLoad` will be fine as well.

Comment: I will post my whole class. I have changes some variable names, other then that, every thing is how it was when I posted the OP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch on first when  read it. Will fix and and notify you here.

Comment: This did seem to be the case. Fixed it. Thank you for your patience and continuous help!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a checkmark accessory to the previously selected cell,
>   the previously_selected_cell variable gets stored even if the app
>   quits/crashes

The way to go will be to control the indexPath in your cellForRowAtIndexPath *implementation* and act if it's equal to previously_selected_cell.integerValue:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    // usual cache lookup, allocation of the cell, etc
    if (indexPath.row == previously_selected_cell.integerValue) {
        // add checkbox here
    } else {
        // remove checkbox
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't implement this method if you are using static table views.

Comment: @jrturton Exactly. I would WANT to use it the way MrTJ posted, but my UITableView is not Dynamic.@ MrTJ Thanks for the method though.

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't read the question enough well. Unfortunately with static UITableViews I don't have relevant experience, maybe someone else will come up with a solution. EDIT - I saw it's already solved :)